# PHP and MS SQL on IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis-7.5

I am building a new Windows Server 2008 R2 server that will be running IIS 7.5 with PHP 5.3.x.  I have IIS running and PHP working correctly with it.  However, our developers are stating that they need to be able to call or access the [mssql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) PHP functions.  The output of a phpinfo() shows that I have [pdo_sqlsrv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) and the [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) extensions installed.  Is there something else that I need to have in order to allow the mssql PHP calls to work?  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSSQL extension is an older extension which has been replaced by the SQLSRV extension (the old MSSQL extension is not supported by Microsoft).

Some details are available in this blog post:
http://blogs.iis.net/donraman/archive/2010/01/25/working-with-microsoft-sql-server-driver-php-sqlsrv-dll-for-php-on-windows.aspx

And on this forum post 
http://forums.iis.net/t/1156341.aspx

If you still want to install it, I believe it was still included in the old (5.2.x and prior) PHP releases.

Comment: Thank you for the links and the information.  This helps a lot.